# Why was the stadium in Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire underground?

Tags: harry-potter, quidditch

It seems strange that the stadium of the Quidditch World Cup in *Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire* was underground. In the movie, we see tunnels to go to the stadium and then people have to go up stairs!!! It would have been easier to climb the hill and go down stairs.

I didn't read the book, but it seems to me that it is so only for the joke about the rain of Lucius Malfoy.

Is there an other reason in the book?

Comment: I don't remember it being underground, but then again it's been a long time since I either read the book or watched the film.

Comment: It wasn't underground, neither in the movie nor in the books.

Comment: Maybe try adjusting the brightness/contrast on your screen.

Answer (score 13):

**The stadium wasn't underground.**

They just went through tunnels because that's how stadiums are generally made. They're a circle and in order to access the stands or the field you have to go across the walls, usually walking in tunnels.

As you can see in the Goblet of Fire movie, [the sky is visible](https://youtu.be/ALVUtORTtZY?t=40) in the stadium. In fact, Harry and the rest are seated at the top of the stands, and behind them you see the night sky. Or when the leprechauns appear.

[image]
[image]

As for the GoF book, no mention is done about underground facilities, but ther's a mention of the sky. When the leprechauns appear:

> Now the rainbow faded and the balls of light reunited and merged; they
> had formed a great shimmering shamrock, which rose up into the sky and
> began to soar over the stands. Something like golden rain seemed to be
> falling from it —
>
> <sub>Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire. Chapter Eight. The Quidditch World Cup.</sub>